I don't undestand why awk removes all lines
I have a probably easy problem but I am having problems finding an explanation.
My data file data.csv looks like this.
field1,field2,field3,field4
abc,def,ghi,jkl
123,456,789,012
mno,pqr,stu,vwx

I want to remove the line where the second column has a value of 456 so the output should look like this.
field1,field2,field3,field4
abc,def,ghi,jkl
mno,pqr,stu,vwx

But my program only prints the first line of output.
awk -F, 'NR>1 { if ($2=456) next } 1' data.csv

I think this should be easy to fix but I don't know what I'm doing wrong and I reviewed the suggested answers but didn't see any obvious explanation.
Any ideas? tia

= assigns a value, == compares.

See: 6.3.2.2 Comparison Operators

Others have already told you = should be == but also consider using more idiomatic awk syntax 'NR==1 || $2!=456' or similar. Of course you only need the NR==1 || part if $2 might have the value 456 in the header line, which is unlikely.

Change "$2=456" to "$2==456". The "=" defines a relationship, while "==" just means equality.

Your code
awk -F, 'NR>1 { if ($2=456) next } 1' data.csv

has typo, it should be
awk -F, 'NR>1 { if ($2==456) next } 1' data.csv

but

remove the line where the second column has a value of 456

can be expressed in more concise way using GNU AWK namely
awk -F, '$2!=456' data.csv

then for data.csv content
field1,field2,field3,field4
abc,def,ghi,jkl
123,456,789,012
mno,pqr,stu,vwx

it will give output
field1,field2,field3,field4
abc,def,ghi,jkl
mno,pqr,stu,vwx

(tested in GNU Awk 5.3.1)
